# MIPS enter user input as string of characters and convert to an integer in base 33

Tags: string, input, decimal, mips, radix

I am new to MIPS and this is my second program in assembly. This is for an academic assignment.

I have to: write a MIPS program that reads a string of up to 4 characters from user input. The program must process the user input with a loop. The program must NOT have subprograms.  Then, assume that the user input is in base 33. Convert that to a decimal integer.

I get errors in my code. Also, I don't know how I would convert the string to an integer to later convert into base 10.

I tried doing something, but this is as far as I got:

```
.data   
str:
.space 6

.word 4      

Ask:  
.asciiz "\nPlease Enter a 4 Characters\n" 


Answer:  
.asciiz "\nYou Entered:\n "    #lets the user know what they entered   


.text  


main:
la $a0, Ask #load address Ask
li $v0, 4 #loads the value 6 into register $v0
syscall

#store input in $t0
move $t0, $v0

li $v0, 8 #get input

la $a0, str
li $a1, 64
syscall

#from here to add
la $a0, Answer
syscall

li $v0, 4 #system call to print 
move $a0, $t0
syscall
```

### Update

OK, so I updated my code. I am not sure though how I would do the system call to access my newly created integers. How can I figure it out?

Here is my updated code:

```
.data
Ask:

.asciiz "\n Please Enter 4 Characters\n" 

userInput:  .space 20

Answer:

.asciiz "\n You Entered : \n"

.text 

main:
#addi $t0, 0


li $v0, 4
la $a0, Ask #display question
syscall

li $v0, 8 #get input
la $a0, userInput
li $a1, 20
syscall

li $v0, 4
la $a0, Answer
syscall

li $v0, 4
la $a0, userInput
syscall

lb $s1, 0($a0)
lb $s2 1($a0)
lb $s3 2($a0)
lb $s4, 3($a0)
lb $t0, 4($a0)
addi $t1, $zero, 10

addi $t5, $zero, 64
addi $t6, $zero 96
addi $s5, $zero, 65
addi $s6, $zero, 97 
addi $t2, $zero, 47  #loads 47 into $t2

addi $t3, $zero,  55

addi $t4, $zero,  87

beq $t0, $t1, Label1

Label1:

bgt $s1, $t2, L1
bgt $s1, $t5, L2
bgt $s1, $t6, L3

L1: 
    addi $s1, $s1, -48  #subtracts 48 from $s1 which is 48 to get int  from 0 to 9 
L2: 
    addi $s1, $s1, -55 #gets values from 10 to 33
L3: 
    addi $s1, $s1, -87  #gets values from 10 to 33 for small caps

bge $s2, $t2, L4
bge $s2, $t5, L5
bge $s2, $t6, L6

L4: 
    addi $s2, $s2, -48
L5: 
    addi $s2, $s2, -55
L6: 
    addi $s2, $s2, -87

bgt $s3, $t2, L7
bgt $s3, $t5, L8 
bgt $s3, $t6, L9

L7: addi $s3, $s3, -48
L8: addi $s3, $s3, -55
L9: addi $s3, $s3, -87


bgt $s4, $t2, L10
bgt $s4, $t5, L11
bgt $s4, $t6, L12

L10: 
    addi $s4, $s4, -48
L11: 
    addi $s4, $s4, -55
L12: 
    addi $s4, $s4 , -87


la $v0, 4 
lw $a0, s4

#last system call of the program will be very last instruction
li $v0, 10
syscall
```

Answer (score 0):

If user input is base 33, then its going to be a string made up of ACSII 0-9 and A-W

So you have no choice except to read it as a string.

Your code:

```
la $a0, Ask #load address Ask
li $v0, 4 #loads the value 6 into register $v0 (wrong comment here)
syscall
```

Will prompt the user for the value, BUT does not read the value so

```
#store input in $t0
move $t0, $v0
```

Wont do anything usefull - you need to read in a string

You code is doing this further along:

```
li $v0, 8 #get input

la $a0, str
li $a1, 64

syscall
```

However, you want to read 4 characters, so should be setting a1 to 4+1 (ie: 5) not 64.

At that point you will have a normal ascii string in the buffer so need to go through each bytes in the buffer (or loop 4 times through the buffer) and for the given character:

- if is is between 0 - 9 => value = thecharacter - '0'
- if it is between A - W = > value = 10 + thecharacter-'A'
- You could also check for a-w, and if doing error checking show an error if it doesn't meet any other the above.

One you have that working, you need to have a value (or register) that you initialize to 0 that is the full base-10 value of all the characters - initialized before you loop through the buffer characters

And then add at the last part of the character loop a statement(s) that effectively is

```
the full_base_10_num = (full_base_10_num * 10) + thecharacter_calculated_value
```

After the loop is done for all characters, you will now have the decimal 10 value you can display.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will do as you advised.